# Free CAD that allows to draw joined arcs

Tags: linux, open-source, cad

I am looking for a CAD that allows to draw joined arcs (circle segments) like one would draw a spline curve.

There are several older CAM machine softwares that only take lines and arcs as input. So for doing a smooth contour it is needed to express them in arcs.

LibreCAD for example allows drawing of arcs, but only by specifying center or three points on the arc, making it nearly impossible to lay out a free form as consecutive arc curve that has smooth tangents at every joining location.